# How to loop an if statement? (Python 3.8)

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, if-statement

After googling and diving through reddit/stackoverflow, I still haven't found a solution.
I am working on a text rpg game and I am trying to loop this statement. This is the part where the player has to choose something in the menu. There are two options:

1. Play the game
2. Go to settings
(and of course quit).

As you can see, if none of those are chosen or the player made a typo, a message should appear and **restart** the statement.

I tried putting the entire thing into a `def function():` and I also tried using `while`. Probably I messed up something.

(English is not my primary language, so I am sorry if it's confusing.)
Here is the code:

```py
while menu_input in menu_options:
    if menu_input.lower() in menu_options.PLAY:
        game.game()
        break
    elif menu_input.lower() in menu_options.HELP:
        from helpsheet import *
        helpsheet.helpmenu()
        break
    else:
        print("Unknown command. For help type 'help'.")
        continue
```

Comment: Note: `in` is something that operates on an iterable value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not asking for the menu input here.  You need something like this:

```
while True:
    menu_input = input("Which option?").lower()
    if menu_input in menu_options.PLAY:
        game.game()
    elif menu_input in menu_options.HELP:
        helpsheet.helpmenu()
    elif menu_input in menu_options.QUIT:
        break
    else:
        print("Unknown command.  For help, type 'help'.")
```

Note that all of these will loop around and ask for input again, except for the "quit" options.

Answer (score 0):

The code you're using should work (or the while loop at least) the only reasons it would not work is the "continue" in the "you didn't give something that would work" check and that your going to loop while the answer is something that you can use. Another thing though, is that in the while loop you need to update the screen. (e.g. have a function that displays your options)

Try:

```
while not menu_input in menu_options:
    clear_screen() #Not an actual function yet
    display_screen() #Not an actual function yet
    if menu_input.lower() in menu_options.PLAY:
        game.game()
        break
    elif menu_input.lower() in menu_options.HELP:
        from helpsheet import *
        helpsheet.helpmenu()
        break
    else:
        print("Unknown command. For help type 'help'.")
        menu_input = input()
```

The "Not an actual function yet" are functions that you need to create for this code to work